# Getting values from the selected option in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the `url` of the selected option. So my main goal is to assign the selected option to the `ng-model` of the `select`

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="ddValue1.value">
    <option ng-repeat="d in ddOptions1" value="{{d.value}}">{{d.text}}</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.ddOptions2 = [
  {value: 'value1', text: 'Text1', url: 'google.com'},
  {value: 'value2', text: 'Text2', url: 'yahoo.com'}
];
$scope.ddValue2 = {};
$scope.ddValue2.value = $scope.ddOptions2[0].value;
```

I tried assigning it by doing `ng-model="ddValue1.url=d.url"`

Comment: Use `ng-options` not `ng-repeat`... See docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) like this

```
<select ng-model="ddValue1"
    ng-options="d.text for d in ddOptions1 track by d.value">
</select>
```

Then you can simply reference `ddValue1.url`

Comment: @user4756836 not sure what you mean. There is no `ng-option`

Comment: sorry, meant... ng-repeat

Comment: @user4756836 why? `ng-options` works **much** better

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in ng-repeat. call ddOptions2

```html
<option ng-repeat="d  in ddOptions2" value="{{d.value}}">{{d.text}}</option>
```